# $('#id').ready ?? Es posible usar la funcion ready de jquery para esperar la carga de un id especifico?

Tags: jquery

quería preguntaros si se podría usar la función ready para esperar la carga de una sección especifica en el DOM.

Pongo un ejemplo del código.

```
$('#id').ready(function(){
    const ptr = window.location.search;
    const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(ptr);
    
    let bj_lead = decodeURI(urlParams.get('bj_lead_name'));
    let bj_date = decodeURI(urlParams.get('bj_event_date'));
    let wbj_time = decodeURI(urlParams.get('bj_event_time'));
}
```

Muchas gracias por vuestras respuestas

Comment: ¿Por qué quieres esperar a que el elemento está `ready`? ¿Lo creas desde el JS por X o Y motivo?

Comment: Si ese elemento está en el DOM lo que debes verificar es que el DOM esté listo (de hecho debería ser así siempre), no el elemento en sí. Imaginate, sería una locura tener que poner escuchadores por cada elemento. Si el elemento está en Window entonces debes escuchar que Window esté ready. Pues eso, escuchar siempre al contenedor más superior, así aseguras que todo lo que contiene está cargado.

Answer (score -1):

Esperar por un elemento en concreto probablemente no sea considerada una buena práctica de programación, pero hay una solución que me parece válida para lo que necesitas en GitHub Gist: https://gist.github.com/jwilson8767/db379026efcbd932f64382db4b02853e.

**Edit**:
Reproduzco a continuación el código a modo de referencia.
En el código se utilizan [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises) de javascript. En el momento de su invocación, la función busca si hay al menos un elemento que cumpla con el criterio del `selector` utilizando `document.querySelector(selector)`. El uso de un [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) permite volver a realizar la comprobación cuando se detectan cambios en el DOM.

```
// MIT Licensed
// Author: jwilson8767

/**
 * Waits for an element satisfying selector to exist, then resolves promise with the element.
 * Useful for resolving race conditions.
 *
 * @param selector
 * @returns {Promise}
 */
export function elementReady(selector) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let el = document.querySelector(selector);
    if (el) {resolve(el);}
    new MutationObserver((mutationRecords, observer) => {
      // Query for elements matching the specified selector
      Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(selector)).forEach((element) => {
        resolve(element);
        //Once we have resolved we don't need the observer anymore.
        observer.disconnect();
      });
    })
      .observe(document.documentElement, {
        childList: true,
        subtree: true
      });
  });
}
```

El ejemplo incluido en el código por su autor es simple y autoexplicativo, eliminar un elemento si existe, o cuando exista.

```
elementReady('#someWidget').then((someWidget)=>{someWidget.remove();});
```